# How to fix login incorrect password even though password is correct windows 10

Tags: windows-10, login

I changed my username in regedit HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->SOFTWARE->Microsoft->Windows NT->ProfileList->ProfileImagePath because there was space between my name. After that I was working in default windows and realized I cannot see my files. So, I put space between my names again and restart. However, when I try to enter the correct password in login, it is saying 'The password is incorrect.' and my username still does not have space between. I don't want to reset my laptop or install new windows since I didn't backup my files. Is there any solutions to login? I am very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a Microsoft Account?  If so, the login is your email. Log into Microsoft Live and check.

https://account.microsoft.com/account?lang=en-us&refd=www.google.ca

If not a Microsoft Account, you need to log in using Safe Mode and enable the built-in Administrator.  Use Settings, Account to see who you are and change the password there, or in Users and Groups.

Be sure to disable the built-in Administrator when done.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hello/login-into-admin-account-under-safe-mode/b0ed7f70-8f27-4efa-9515-24929ad63fb2

> Hold down the shift key on your keyboard while clicking the Power
> button on the screen (while on the login screen) Continue to hold down
> the shift key while clicking Restart Continue to hold down the shift
> key until the Advanced Recovery Options menu appears Click
> Troubleshoot Click Advanced options Click Command Prompt At the
> command prompt, enter: net user administrator active:yes Close command
> prompt, and restart You should now see an Administrator account you
> can select (this has no password)

> I changed my username in regedit
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->SOFTWARE->Microsoft->Windows
> NT->ProfileList->ProfileImagePath

I suggest you not use the registry in future for changing user names. I hope everything works.

If not, then "I tampered with the registry" = Very likely need to re-install Windows.

Boot with a Windows USB Key (Media Creation Link) and recover the data you need. Put it on an external USB Drive.  Then reinstall Windows.